# How align text to be displayed in the middle of parent image side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to make a responsive web-page, using html, css and bootstrap.

How do i center text, relative to image position? Image must be at the left side of text.

Here is some code:

```
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="background-color: black;">
                    <div>
                        <img style="float: left;" src="~/Content/img/Assets/img1.png" alt="" width="65" height="65" class="" />
                        <div>
                            Hello World!
                        </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?.... This doesn't really say much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try to not use inline style
2. col-xs-1 is too small, use col-xs-4 or col-xs-6 or col-xs-12 ?

```css
.mycontainer {
  background-color: black;
}

.myimg {
  vertical-align: middle
}

.mytext {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="col-xs-4 mycontainer">
  <div>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="~/Content/img/Assets/img1.png" alt="" width="65" height="65" />
    <span class="mytext">
      Hello World!
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Parent element is `col-xs-1` which is shorter than it's child content.
- Increase parent element size to something like `col-xs-4` and tweak to your benefit.
- Also as Micheal pointed, avoid floating images, below a flexbox suggestion:

```css
.imgCont {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="imgCont">
    <img src="~/Content/img/Assets/img1.png" alt="" width="65" height="65" class="" />
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you still wish to use `float`, snippet below (use `line-height` for text vertical centering):

```css
.text {
  line-height: 65px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: black;">
  <div>
    <img style="float: left;" src="~/Content/img/Assets/img1.png" alt="" width="65" height="65" class="" />
    <div class="text">
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the first flexbox snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't float the image, and add `.text-center` to the parent. You probably also want to use a wider column class so it isn't so cramped in a small viewport.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="col-xs-1" style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="~/Content/img/Assets/img1.png" alt="" width="65" height="65" class="" />
    <div>
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```